# Angular button in one view starts countdown in another view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, view, timeout

I'm about to go crazy here with AngularJS.

Is there a way in AngularJS that by clicking a button in a view, "View B" you start a 10 second countdown timer in a "Home View"

And if you click a button in "View C" you start a 20 second countdown in that same "Home View"?

Thank you very much for answers!

Comment: It's all about collecting timer value, just store in a variable and then use that variable in that view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don´t seem to work it out. Do you have a simple plunkr example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is related with AngularJS Modularization & Dependency Injection

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html

this will help you